# Getting Difference in count of "Total Number of links" on webpage through Selenium and Browser Development Tools

Tags: selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I have written code to count total number of link on Web Page. I used JavascriptExecutor in selenium of that. But issue is that I am getting different count for total number link Java Script command in Selenium and same in browser console. Here are testing details:

Website under test : https://www.ebay.com/
Test: Total number of links on Home Page of Ebay.

Selenium code and result:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.ebay.com/");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    System.out.println(js.executeScript(" return document.links.length"));
```

Result : 422

But when I executed same in browser console then I am getting 440. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pItge.png)

I am unable to understand difference here. Please someone help me to understand

Comment: The content is dynamic and its changing, its not the exact same page on each load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be pretty tough to answer your question as you haven't mentioned on which browser console you executed the `JavaScript` command :

```
document.links.length
```

How ever the `Test Result` which you observe through **`ChromeDriver`** is just identical with my quick test result which I observe through **`Chrome Development Console`** i.e. the exact figure of **422**. See the snapshot below :

[image: document.links.length]

However, it is worth to mention that **`IEDriverServer`** and **`GeckoDriver`** both being **W3C Compliant** and **`Google Chrome`** and **`PhantomJS`** still being **OSS Compliant** renders the **`HTML DOM Tree`** through different protocols and standards. Though the difference in **DOM Tree** rendering `Mechanism` can be insignificant but `delta` difference in the `End Results` is enough to **FAIL** your `Validation`.

Hence the solution would be to always choose any single variant (either of **`IE`**/**`Firefox`**/**`Chrome`**/**`PhantomJS`**) of **`WebDriver`**/**`Web Browser`** combination to validate for **`Manual`** and **`Automated`** `Test Results`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got 440 in Mozilla. Screen shot which I shared in my question is of Mozilla Developer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar As you have used ChromeDriver my Answer was based on Chrome. I have detailed out the reason for different output within my answer. If my Answer have catered to your question please Accept the Answer by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer which is just below the Votedown arrow so the tick mark turns green.