# java.lang.AssertionError while asserting text with Safari but passes with Chrome & FireFox using Selenium TestNG

Tags: selenium, safari, testng, native, assertion

I have a TestNG Selenium Script that will run in Chrome and Firefox, but fails when its run in Safari. I'm using an Assert to verify a name and Safari is having none of it. I'm still a noob so I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks for any help

HTML:

```
<a href="https://xxxxxx/users/show/733981" target="_blank" xpath="1">Jeff Smith</a>
```

Safari Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [JEFF SMITH] but found [Jeff Smith]
```

Code trial:

```js
@Test(priority = 4)
public void VerifyGuest() {
    WebElement guestName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Jeff Smith')]"));
    String expectedName = "JEFF SMITH";
    String actualName = guestName.getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(actualName, expectedName);
    System.out.println("Reservation Code Belongs to " + actualName);
}
```

Comment: I get the same kind of error in Safari when using the assert to verify this name too .        
                                                                                                                                     <div class="tile_l" xpath="1" style="outline: orange dashed 2px 
!important;">
                                Mike Smith
                            </div>

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Mike Smith] but found [
                                Mike Smith
                            ]

Comment: In the sample you give in the 1st comment, the text does look like with spaces " Mike Smith ", and in that case it is natural for equals to fail.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE, with the actual answer.

The `getText()` method (or "getElementText" webdriver command) returns the text as rendered ([at least according to the specs it should](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-text)).
The page obviously applies some css transforms on the text - the node value is capitalized (Jeff Smith), but it is returned as JEFF SMITH (that is what you also 
 see in the browser, right?); that's quite easy to do - with a style like `text-transform: uppercase;`.

So Chrome & Firefox are following the webdriver specs, while Safari obviously isn't yet - it doesn't return the rendered form, but the one that is in the source.

So if you need to just verify the content of the element, I'd suggest normalizing its textual value - removing excessive whitespace, and converting it to lowercase.
In Java that's done with `st.trim().toLowerCase()` where `st` is your string variable's name.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: How to strip white space and lowercase? `st.trim().toLowerCase()` where `st` is your string variable.

Comment: @JavaNoob found your problem, see the update of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll the "trimming" solution and let you know how it works out. Thanks for all the help you guys rule!

Comment: I changed the expected Name to "jeff smith" and add String actualName = guestName.getText().trim().toLowerCase(); and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it did! Strictly for the trimming - have in mind html rendering substitutes multiple spaces with a single one - e.g. "Java<space><space><space>Noob" is shown as "Java<space>Noob" (except when `&nbsp;` is used). So you have to accommodate for that if your desired string has them.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no error in your code block but there is a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) sitution due to *WebDriver* using [Browser’s Native XPath capabilities](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath).

### Browser’s Native XPath capabilities

At a high level, WebDriver uses a browser’s native XPath capabilities wherever possible. On those browsers that don’t have native XPath support, *Selenium* have provided their own implementation. This can lead to some unexpected behaviour due to the differences in the various XPath engines.

[image: Browser_Native_Xpath_Capabilities]

As an example, for the following piece of HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="example" />
<INPUT type="text" name="other" />
```

If your line of code is:

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
```

The following number of matches will be found:

[image: Xpath_Native_Support]

### Solution

As the element was identified based on the *text* as **Jeff Smith** you need to match with the *rendered text* which is **Jeff Smith**. So your effective code block will be:

```
@Test(priority = 4)
public void VerifyGuest() {
    WebElement guestName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Jeff Smith')]"));
    String expectedName = "Jeff Smith";
    String actualName = guestName.getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(actualName, expectedName);
    System.out.println("Reservation Code Belongs to " + actualName);
}
```

**Note**: Identifying an element with XPath's *text()* and retriving the text through `getText()` isn't a proper way to *Assert* any text. Perhaps the desired element should be identified with some other effective [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

Comment: I've tried using "Jeff Smith" (instead of JEFF SMITH). Safari will Pass, but that causes Chrome and Safari to fail

Comment: Can I use ".getAttribute " to get the "Jeff Smith" info instead?

Comment: @JavaNoob That is what I exactly explained through an example quoting from the documentation. Safari and Chrome behavior is not documented. That's on my to-do list :)

Comment: The DOM for Safari and Chrome are slightly Different. Would the Style Attribute be causing the issue?                                                                                      
Safari DOM:
<a href="https://xxxxxx/users/show/733981" target="_blank" xpath="1">Jeff Smith</a>            
 Chrome DOM:                  
<a href="https://xxxxxx/users/show/733981" target="_blank" xpath="1" style="">Jeff Smith</a>

Comment: @JavaNoob Now you have hit the right chord. Of-coarse different browser will render the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) differently. See: [Getting Difference in count of “Total Number of links” on webpage through Selenium and Browser Development Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955774/getting-difference-in-count-of-total-number-of-links-on-webpage-through-seleni/47956061#47956061). `style` and `xpath="1"` attribute makes the difference here.